# Opening 2 files and assigning them to 2 Sets in Python 3

Tags: python, file, set

Here is my sample code. It works. But I am sure there is an easier way to store values in a set.  I only know how to store them in a list first then transfer them into a set.  The reason why I'm moving them into sets is to take advantage of the difference() method. Just asking the community for some advice.  Everyone's input is well appeciated!

```
a_file = open(r'c:\a.csv', 'r')
b_file = open(r'c:\b.csv', 'r')

a_list = a_file.read().splitlines()
b_list = b_file.read().splitlines()

a_file.close()
b_file.close()

"""
Here, I am declaring 2 sets and then clear them of their 
values before storing the values from the lists.  
If I didn't do it this way, Python would think these were 
DICTIONARY datatypes instead and produce an syntax error.
"""

a_set = {1} #Just to get the program to recognize it as a set.
b_set.clear() #Then clear the data so that it is empty but stays as a set datatype.
a_set = {1}
b_set.clear()

a_set.update(a_list)
b_set.update(b_list)

difference_list = a_set.difference(b_set)
```

Comment: you can convert list to set by using `set()` method. `set(a_list)`. you are making your simple program to complicated

Comment: Ahh, so instead of doing the above... I can simple do this instead ...a_set = set(a_list).  This is a lot easier.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note that you can get an empty set by using `set()`. You don't need to call `clear()` on it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `set` to convert a list to a set on the spot. So this will be enough:

```py
a_file = open(r'c:\a.csv', 'r')
b_file = open(r'c:\b.csv', 'r')

a_set = set(a_file.readlines())
b_set = set(b_file.readlines())

a_file.close()
b_file.close()

difference_list = a_set.difference(b_set)
```

But I would also recommend to apply `with` statement to perform basic file operations (open, close, etc) and ensure that in case of almost any exceptions they all will be closed properly. In that case the code will look like this:

```py
with open(r'c:\a.csv', 'r') as a_file, open(r'c:\b.csv', 'r') as b_file:
    a_set = set(a_file.readlines())
    b_set = set(b_file.readlines())

difference_list = a_set.difference(b_set)
```

Comment: I love the combo, Thankyou!

Comment: Thanks again for all of your valuable knowledge.  I learned a lot today.

Comment: @Dgun Thank you for a properly prepared question with a code sample. It's always much easier to help with all that information you provide us.

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap a `set()` around the list.

```
def readfile(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as fh:
        return fh.read().splitlines()

diff = set(readfile("file1.txt")).difference(set(readfile("file2.txt")))
```

Comment: The `.difference()` method will convert an Iterable to a set automatically. Therefore, you could simplify the final line as `diff = set(readfile("file1.txt")).difference(readfile("file2.txt"))`.

Comment: Nice, I like the way you used a function in your example.  Much appreciated!